# Metal Gear Solid 3 HD: "King of the Jungle" Achievement

Tags: xbox-360, ps3, metal-gear-solid-3-snake-eater, metal-gear-solid-hd-collection

Does anyone know if you have to eat every type of animal on ONE playthrough, or does it accumulate like Kerotans when you load from a previous playthrough?

I think I captured just about everything my first time around, apart from one or two things, I'd rather not have to do it all again for my second playthrough.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this trophy guide](http://www.ps3trophies.org/game/metal-gear-solid-3-snake-eater-hd/guide/):

> [...] To earn the title MARKHOR you must collect all 48 different types of animal and plant life. That is all Snakes, Birds, Fruit, Mushrooms, Fish, Frogs and various other non-specific flora/fauna. You do not need to eat, just hold all 48 items in your inventory at least once **in a single playthrough** [...]

So, to answer your question, you **do** have to collect all animals/plants on a single playthorugh, but you **don't** have to eat them all.